# How to redirect based on visitor's IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver

I need to create a landing page that will automatically redirect a visitor to the correct country page of a website by working  out their location from their IP address.

This is an EPiServer 4 site. How would you go about doing this and does EPiServer have this functionality built in?

Comment: Couldn't you look at the browsers language also? I am guessing you have already obtained some lookup IP range tables to do this against?

Comment: Well, I managed to implement this using a geolocation database (from maxmind.com) but then the issue of search engines being adversely affected meant that I removed this functionality.

Using the browser language does sound like a good idea actually, but in the end I just let the user select their country and stored the selection in a cookie so they would not have to select it on subsequent visits.

Comment: Pretty sure Episerver 4 didn't have that built-in, but I haven't worked with version 4 since approximately 2008. :(

Comment: Thanks @TedNyberg! Fun to see an old pro from the EpiServer world popping up :)

Comment: Haha, I choose to take that as a compliment... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a [Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) Service provider, of which there are [many](http://ipinfo.info/html/geolocation_2.php).

However, wouldn't it be better to let the user choose their location, lest they are visiting through a proxy, or temporarily on vacation or something?

Comment: I'm using data MaxMind (5th on your list). They have a free database and API code with examples.

We're going to have a dropdown list of countries on all pages so people can get to the right country if they are on holiday or using a proxy. But out of interest, what's a proxy and why would someone be using one?

Comment: A proxy is a another computer that you connect to the internet via. As far as the rest of the internet sees, your IP is that of the proxy. So if your proxy is located in a different country, the geolocation service will incorrectly identify the location of the user. Proxies are used for a number of reasons such as anonymous surfing or bypassing regional restrictions eg from countries like UAE, or China, which have heavily filtered web access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splitterhq](http://splitterhq.com/insights/redirect-based-on-country)

> ***Automatically redirect users to different links based on what country, region or city they are in to show targeted content and increase your conversion rates.***